# parseInt on array and sum issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using JQuery, I populated an array from checkbox values. I then created for loop to loop through the array, parse the checkbox values to integers, sum them and assign the value to a variable "total". When I run this, I get is not a number, I suspect something is up with for loop. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here. And please pardon me if my coding is not as clean as it should be, I'm just starting off in JS.

```js
// create array and push selected checkbox values to it
    var allVals = [];

    $('input:checkbox[name=brand]:checked').each(function() {
      allVals.push($(this).val());
      //allVals.map(number);
    });
       
    for (var i=0; i < allVals.length; i++) {
      var total
      allVals[i] = parseInt(allVals[i]); 
      total += allVals[i] << 0;
      alert(total);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that your current answers are half-wrong -- you indeed have to initialize `total` to zero (otherwise `undefined + number` will be `NaN`), but you do *not* have to relocate that variable outside of the loop, because *Javascript does not have loop scopes*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**first** of all you have to create the total variable outside of your for loop
then  initialize it to zero

```
var total = 0;

for (var i=0; i < allVals.length; i++) {

  allVals[i] = parseInt(allVals[i],10); 
  total += allVals[i];
  console.log(total);
}
```

**Second** Because  you are adding a number to an uninitialized variable
you are getting a NaN result

for example

```
var c;
c +=1; //this will be NaN(not a numeric number)
```

the reason is that when you initialize a variable JavaScript knows the right data type
that should be given to that variable

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to get this to work. I appreciate it!

Comment: One recommendation is to always set the radian to 10 when using parseInt or you can end up with octal numbers

Comment: A good notice but if you don't specify the base, the default base is base 10 so parseInt('20') <=> parseInt('20',10)

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `total` inside the `for` so it gets reset each time - I modified your code a bit, but this should work:

```
var numbers = $('input:checkbox[name=brand]:checked').map(function() {
    return isNaN(this.value) ? 0 : this.value;
}).get();

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
}

alert(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be as simple as:

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').on('click', sum);
  
function sum(e) {
  var total = $('[type=checkbox]:checked')
               .toArray()
               .reduce( function (a,b) {return a + +b.value;}, 0 );
  $('[data-sum]').attr('data-sum', total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
[data-sum] {
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  width: 100px
}

[data-sum]:before {
   content: '\03A3  'attr(data-sum);
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="23.23"> 23.23<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3.33"> 3.33<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="15.00"> 15.00<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1101.22"> 1101.22<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="78.10"> 78.10<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="122.05"> 122.05<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="435.00"> 435.00<br>
<div data-sum="0"></div>
```